# Android Constraint by center

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have guideline 60% from top and LinearLayout with bottom constrain to that guideline (so my LinearLayout will 60% of screen). Now Im need to put half of CardView to the bottom of that LinearLayout (screenshot added).

CardView height is wrap_content, cause will be added dynamically so I dont know height and cannot use something like margin bottom -50dp.

Thats what I have:

[image: Thats what I have]

I need something like that:

[image]

I cannot find future like constrain by center. Could you help me, please.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to set the top anchor of cardview to be connected to the bottom anchor of the linear layout (or to the guideline), and do the same for the bottom anchor. With both top and bottom anchors pointing to the same target, the cardview will be centered vertically on that target. Also, you might not need that linearlayout, depending on what you do. Check the [chains functionality](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains) in `ConstraintLayout`.

[image]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="28dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="156dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
```

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score -1):

The eaiest way is to do this in code at runtime.  Wait until the height has been calculated, then add a top margin of -.5*height.